# Is hidden text bad for search engine ranking?

Tags: google, ranking, hidden-text

I am using hidden text on one of my websites for better search engine ranking.

However, many articles suggest it is better not to use hidden text. Does using hidden text with keywords in the webpage affect rankings? Does Google block such types of site that use hidden text like using the same color for the text as for the background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

> Hiding text or links in your content can cause your site to be
> perceived as untrustworthy since it
> presents information to search engines
> differently than to visitors.
> ...
>
> If your site is perceived to contain
> hidden text and links that are
> deceptive in intent, your site may be
> removed from the Google index, and
> will not appear in search results
> pages.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66353

Comment: but how will google find it?

Comment: It looks at the font colour and the background colour and notices they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is the very definition of black hat SEO and probably the most obvious. Doing this is asking for a ban.