# is it a good seo practice to put relative keywords in a hidden div?

Tags: seo, search-engines, css, keywords, hidden-text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [hidden texts and page rank](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15060/hidden-texts-and-page-rank)

I was wondering what would happen if we put some (around 25) relative keywords in the page using a hidden div so that the actual user does not see them but the search engines do?
do search engines consider this to be `keyword fraud`(!) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [keyword stuffing](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66358). Don't do it.

If you can find an honest way to get some of those terms into the page itself, like a sidebar blurb explaining what your site is for, instructional text, etc. then you're generally fine.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern search engines like Google don't even read keywords Meta tag of the site and putting keywords in hidden div is definitely a bad idea. I agree with what Su said.

Other ways are putting keywords in image alt tags, HTML page Title etc.

For search engines the best keywords are one which other sites uses while linking to you. 
In other words the keywords in anchor tags `(<a href)` are most useful.

> Always try to create pages for
>   communities and not for search
>   engines.