# Does google crawl css scripts to check of hidden content

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, keywords, web-crawlers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [hidden texts and page rank](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15060/hidden-texts-and-page-rank)

Does googlebot crawl CSS scripts to determine if content is hidden or not? If so, is it advisable to hide or not to hide content to improve on the SEO of a page.
My main reason for asking is that I would like to improve on my ranking for certain keywords.